# Onmouseover reverts to original text

Tags: jquery, html, css, onmouseover

So I've applied onmouseover to the Angelina Jolie image in order to change the text of the element above which reads "some sample text". How can I make it revert back to the original text, which reads, "Your Daily dose of Contrabang". Thank you in advance for your help. The Jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/cntra/VSCXy/9/

HTML:

```
<div class="columa">     
<div id="text-display">
<span id="targetElm">Your Daily Dose of Contrabang</span>
</div>

<div class="morphing-tinting">
<a href="#" class="changeTextClass" rel="targetElm|some sample text">
<span class="image-wrap" style="position:relative; left: 0px; top:0; display:inline-block;        
background:url
(http://www.howmuchdotheyweigh.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/angelina-jolie.jpg)
 no-repeat center center; width: 250px; height: 250px;">
</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
  #text-display
 {top:; position: relative;
 display:inline-block;padding:5px 10px; 
 font-family: sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:50px; 
 color: white; text-align: center; line-height: 1.2em;margin:0px;   
 background-color:#E94F78;}


.morphing-tinting .image-wrap {
position: absolute;

-webkit-transition: 1s;
-moz-transition: 1s;
transition: 1s;

-webkit-border-radius: 30em;
-moz-border-radius: 30em;
border-radius: 30em;
}

.morphing-tinting .image-wrap:hover{
-webkit-border-radius: 30em;
-moz-border-radius: 30em;
border-radius: 30em;
}
```

JS

```
$('.changeTextClass').hover(function(){
    var elmData = $(this).attr('rel').split('|');
    $('#'+elmData[0]).text(elmData[1]);
});

    var elmData,origText;
$('.changeTextClass').hover(function(){
    elmData = $(this).attr('rel').split('|');
    origText = $('#'+elmData[0]).text();
    $('#'+elmData[0]).text(elmData[1]);
 }, function(){
    $('#'+elmData[0]).text(origText);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache your original text and use the handlerOut callback to set the text back to original.

```
.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )
```

So, in the DOM ready, I would do this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var originalText = $('#targetElm').text();

  $('.changeTextClass').hover(
    function() {
      var elmData = $(this).attr('rel').split('|');
      $('#targetElm').text(elmData[1]);
    },
    function() {
      $('#targetElm').text(originalText);
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle works just fine, all you have in there is the old hover which is ruining the new affect. See: http://jsfiddle.net/VSCXy/10/ (note I removed Angelina because she was NSFW)

updates js section:

```
var elmData,origText;
$('.changeTextClass').hover(function(){
    elmData = $(this).attr('rel').split('|');
    origText = $('#'+elmData[0]).text();
    $('#'+elmData[0]).text(elmData[1]);
 }, function(){
    $('#'+elmData[0]).text(origText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to the following:

```
var elmData,origText;
$('.changeTextClass').hover(function(){
    elmData = $(this).attr('rel').split('|');
    origText = $('#targetElm').text();
    $('#'+elmData[0]).text(elmData[1]);
 }, function(){
    $('#'+elmData[0]).text(origText);
});
```

You delete the first hover function and in the second you change the content of origText and all works like wanted.